# OnClick Listener button pressed state

Tags: android, android-button

I am having four button where user should select one button at a time.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/btnindicator"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/btnbg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20dip"
    android:text="Button1"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/btnindicator"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/btnbg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20dip"
    android:text="Button2"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/btnindicator"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/btnbg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20dip"
    android:text="Button3"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/btnindicator"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/btnbg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20dip"
    android:text="Button4"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

here is the btnindicator.xml which is used to show pressed/focused state of a button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="@color/LightBlue" android:startColor="@color/DodgerBlue" />
            <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="@color/PowderBlue" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape>
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="@color/LightBlue" android:startColor="@color/DodgerBlue" />
            <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="@color/PowderBlue" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="@color/Wheat" android:startColor="@color/WhiteSmoke" />
            <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="@color/FloralWhite" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Here is the code to listen on Click listener

```
public Button button1,button2,button3,button4;
button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Clicked button1");
                selected = true;
            }
        });
```

But the problem is the click event is triggered for the non focused button only if the button clicked twice.

Ex: If button1 is pressed then if i click twice on button2 then button2 on click listener will get invoked.

I changed with `button1.setOnFocusChangeListener()` and `button1.setOnTouchListener()` where both are working fine.

But i am not able to get what's the problem with setOnClickListener method ..

Comment: Focusable in touch mode is a property that you can set yourself either from code or XML. However, it should be used sparingly and only in very specific situations as it breaks consistency with Android normal behavior.  http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2008/12/touch-mode.html , that why your onclick listener is not working properly

Answer (score 1):

Set to your root layout

```
android:splitMotionEvents="false"
```

Hope, this will help you.